# Android Studio 1.3.2 No Module

Tags: android-studio

Trying to follow this tutorial to run a new android project on a samsung device.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

However, I'm stuck in this step:

> **Run the app from Android Studio**
>
> 1) Select one of your project's files and click Run from the toolbar.

I've selected the MyLoginActivity.java file but I can't click run (it's grey out)

[image]

I've tried to “Edit Configuration" add a "Android Application" but "Module" is empty:

I've tried to "Sync Project with Gradle Files". But the "Module" is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

There was an ampersand (`&`) in the directory path! Creating a new project in a new directory without the `&` symbol solved all the issues.

No issue when opening a new project for XCode.